# Cannot update `max_wal_senders` parameter, always set to 1

Tags: postgresql, wal, pg-config

I'm trying to increase the `max_wal_senders` param and no matter how or what I set it to, it always shows up as `1`.

Updated postgresql.conf, only one instanced of `max_wal_senders` and it's set to 10.

I've also used  `alter system set max_wal_senders = 10` and verified it's showing as 10 in the auto.conf.

I've restarted the DB multiple times, and updating other config changes like `max_connections` are showing as updated when looking at `show max_connections` so I know the config I'm updating is the correct one.

In running `select * from pg_settings where name = 'max_wal_senders';`

Current value is 1, `boot_value` is set to 10, and the `reset_value` is set to 1.

It seems like it's getting reset or the changes just aren't being applied for some reason, but not having the issue with any other parameter. Anything I'm missing?

Should also be noted that I'm running Postgres though docker and my method for restarting postgres is simply restarting the docker container. (again, this works for other config changes, so not sure if it matters)

```
{
"select * from pg_settings where name = 'max_wal_senders'": [
    {
        "name" : "max_wal_senders",
        "setting" : "1",
        "unit" : null,
        "category" : "Replication \/ Sending Servers",
        "short_desc" : "Sets the maximum number of simultaneously running WAL sender processes.",
        "extra_desc" : null,
        "context" : "postmaster",
        "vartype" : "integer",
        "source" : "command line",
        "min_val" : "0",
        "max_val" : "262143",
        "enumvals" : null,
        "boot_val" : "10",
        "reset_val" : "1",
        "sourcefile" : null,
        "sourceline" : null,
        "pending_restart" : false
    }
]}
```

In checking my `docker-compose.yml`, in the postgres command I'm setting cmax_wal_senders=1.

```
postgres -cwal_level=archive -carchive_mode=on -carchive_command="/usr/bin/wget wale/wal-push/%f -O -" -carchive_timeout=600 -ccheckpoint_timeout=700 -cmax_wal_senders=1
```

I've updated this to 10 though and have restarted the container and am still seeing 1.

```
postgres -cwal_level=archive -carchive_mode=on -carchive_command="/usr/bin/wget wale/wal-push/%f -O -" -carchive_timeout=600 -ccheckpoint_timeout=700 -cmax_wal_senders=10
```

Comment: Do you have a `conf.d` or other directory that postgresql.conf includes?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Nope, no other files included.

Comment: Please add the complete result of the `pg_settings` query.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation can be seen in the output from `pg_settings`: the source of the setting is "command line". That means that the server was started with that explicit parameter value, e.g.

```bash
postgres -c max_wal_senders=1 -D datadir
```

That will override the setting in the configuration files.

Comment: Can this not be changed once the server is started with the value though? I updated the docker-compose command to set max_wal_senders=10 and restarted the container, but I'm guessing the 1 value is still stored on a volume somewhere.  I would have figured `alter system` would be a way to adjust this.

Comment: No, this cannot be changed once the server has started. You'll have to modify the way PostgreSQL is started.